# viewing sonarqube duplicate code

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-web

In sonarqube 5.6.4, how do I view the duplicate code blocks?  In 4.5, there was a mostly hidden UI element under the duplication metric.  Now it does nothing.

Since the issue is attached to a top of the file, how can I tell what I need to fix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Duplications are marked by a yellow-orange bar in the left margin. Click it to see details:

[image]

Comment: Ok, i see that now.  Is there no way to filter it down to only duplicated code like in 4.5?  some of our files are 10-20k lines (that is next year's battle)  and the duplication are hard to find.

Comment: In v9.5, the blocks are grey.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty similar to how it was in 4.5.x actually. When scrolling through the sources, look for the orange marker on the left next to the line number. Clicking on it will give you details on where the duplication comes from ( [screenshot](http://i63.tinypic.com/2efsruo.png) ).